# Function runs twice if nested async calls are executed and once otherwise. Need help pre-determining when this will happen

Tags: swift

**func handleGetAllPhotoURLs** is called from the line below and I have confirmed that the line of code only executes once with breakpoints.

```
_ = FlickrClient.getAllPhotoURLs(currentPin: self.currentPin, fetchCount: fetchCount, completion: self.handleGetAllPhotoURLs(pin:urls:error:))
```

According to output from my print statements, the function runs twice because it prints two lines of output if urls.count is non-zero.  However, if urls.count is zero then I only get one print statement that states "urls.count  ---> 0"

**handleGetAllPhotoURLs ---> urls.count  ---> 0**   //this line is always printed

**handleGetAllPhotoURLs ---> urls.count  ---> 21** //this line is only printed if the urls parameter is not empty

```
func handleGetAllPhotoURLs(pin: Pin, urls: [URL], error: Error?){
    print("handleGetAllPhotoURLs ---> urls.count  ---> \(urls.count)")

    let backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext! = dataController.backGroundContext
    if let error = error {
        print("func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect... \n\(error)")
        return
    }

    let pinId = pin.objectID
    backgroundContext.perform {
        let backgroundPin = backgroundContext.object(with: pinId) as! Pin
        backgroundPin.urlCount = Int32(urls.count)
        try? backgroundContext.save()
    }

    for (index, currentURL) in urls.enumerated() {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: currentURL, completionHandler: { (imageData, response, error) in
            guard let imageData = imageData else {return}
            connectPhotoAndPin(dataController: self.dataController, currentPin:  pin , data: imageData, urlString: currentURL.absoluteString, index: index)
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

In addition, I have a UILabel that only reveals itself when urls.count is zero and I only want to reveal it when urls is empty.

Right now, if urls is not empty, the app is very quickly flashing the empty message UILabel.  Which now makes sense to me because print statement shows that urls array is temporarily empty.

Is there a way for me to determine to avoid flashing the empty message UILabel to user when urls.count is non-zero?

edit:  Added code below based on request.  The function below is called to obtain [URL] in completion handler.  Then the completion handler is fed into:
**func handleGetAllPhotoURLs(pin: Pin, urls: [URL], error: Error?)**

```
class func getAllPhotoURLs(currentPin: Pin, fetchCount count: Int, completion: @escaping (Pin, [URL], Error?)->Void)-> URLSessionTask?{
    let latitude = currentPin.latitude
    let longitude = currentPin.longitude
    let pageNumber = currentPin.pageNumber


    let url = Endpoints.photosSearch(latitude, longitude, count, pageNumber).url

    var array_photo_URLs = [URL]()
    var array_photoID_secret = [[String: String]]()
    var array_URLString = [String]()
    var array_URLString2 = [String]()
    var count = 0

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let dataObject = data, error == nil else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(currentPin, [], error)
            }
            return
        }

        do {
            let temp = try JSONDecoder().decode(PhotosSearch.self, from: dataObject)
            temp.photos.photo.forEach{
                let tempDict = [$0.id : $0.secret]
                array_photoID_secret.append(tempDict)

                let photoURL = FlickrClient.Endpoints.getOnePicture($0.id, $0.secret)
                let photoURLString = photoURL.toString
                array_URLString.append(photoURLString)

                getPhotoURL(photoID: $0.id, secret: $0.secret, completion: { (urlString, error) in
                    guard let urlString = urlString else {return}
                    array_URLString2.append(urlString)
                    array_photo_URLs.append(URL(string: urlString)!)
                    count = count + 1
                    if count == temp.photos.photo.count {
                        completion(currentPin, array_photo_URLs, nil)
                    }
                })
            }
            completion(currentPin, [], nil)
            return
        } catch let conversionErr {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(currentPin, [], conversionErr)
            }
            return
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    return task
}
```

Comment: The contents of the function don't affect how many times the function is being called. We have to see how you are calling that method.

Comment: Hi.  Made edit that can hopefully provide more info.  class func getAllPhotoURLs() returns a completion handler which then goes into func handleGetAllPhotoURLs().  If there's anything else I can provide to help, please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `do` block, you are calling `completion` twice. Please see the correction,

```
do {
    let temp = try JSONDecoder().decode(PhotosSearch.self, from: dataObject)
    if temp.photos.photo.isEmpty == false {
       temp.photos.photo.forEach{
        let tempDict = [$0.id : $0.secret]
        array_photoID_secret.append(tempDict)

        let photoURL = FlickrClient.Endpoints.getOnePicture($0.id, $0.secret)
        let photoURLString = photoURL.toString
        array_URLString.append(photoURLString)

        getPhotoURL(photoID: $0.id, secret: $0.secret, completion: { (urlString, error) in
            guard let urlString = urlString else {return}
            array_URLString2.append(urlString)
            array_photo_URLs.append(URL(string: urlString)!)
            count = count + 1
            if count == temp.photos.photo.count {
                completion(currentPin, array_photo_URLs, nil)
            }
        })
      }
    } else {
        completion(currentPin, [], nil)
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I was looking in all the wrong places.  Didn't realize I was returning completion handler twice.